# Rails - submit_tag with bootstrap input-group-addon span class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have a Rails app in which I have a form where I want to use a `text_field` and a `submit_tag` using bootstrap's `input-group-addon` span class. As on this page: [bootstrap input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups).

My form currently looks like this:

```
.input-group
  = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Filter...", class: "form-control no-border-radius"
  = submit_tag "<span class=\"input-group-addon\">Search</span>".html_safe
```

But it doesn't have the Bootstrap styling as I want. So, what is the correct way to apply a span styling so a `submit_tag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is what you are after:

```
.input-group
  = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Filter...", class: "form-control no-border-radius"
  %span.input-group-btn
    = submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-default"
```